# problem in multi step form with formik in react with nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/building-multi-step-form-with-formik-yup-forked-covfp)

It is simple form that I founded in internet, after all steps when I submitting the form in console I can see the following data:

```
   {
     "firstName": "asas",
     "lastName": "wdw",
     "address1": "asasas",
     "city": "1",
     "zipcode": "11111",
     "country": "222",
     "useAddressForPaymentDetails": false,
     "nameOnCard": "AAA",
     "cardNumber": "111123456",
     "expiryDate": "2027-09-26T08:51:30.737Z",
     "cvv": "123",
     }
```

But I want to transfer it in nested object as you see in below. I want create `payment` object for payment step

```
   {
     "firstName": "asas",
     "lastName": "wdw",
     "address1": "asasas",
     "city": "1",
     "zipcode": "11111",
     "country": "222",
     "useAddressForPaymentDetails": false,
      payment:{
        "nameOnCard": "AAA",
        "cardNumber": "111123456",
        "expiryDate": "2027-09-26T08:51:30.737Z",
        "cvv": "123",
       },
     }
```

I already change somethings in project to get that result:

initialValues:

```
   const {
      formField: {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        address1,
        city,
        zipcode,
        country,
        useAddressForPaymentDetails,
        payment,
      }
    } = checkoutFormModel;

    export default {
       [firstName.name]: "",
       [lastName.name]: "",
       [address1.name]: "",

      [payment.nameOnCard.name]: "",
      [payment.cardNumber.name]: "",
      [payment.expiryDate.name]: "",
      [payment.cvv.name]: ""
};
```

checkoutModel:

```
   export default {
     formId: "checkoutForm",
     formField: {
       payment: {
         nameOnCard: {
         name: "nameOnCard",
         label: "Name on card*",
       },
        cardNumber: {
        name: "cardNumber",
        label: "Card number*",
       }
    ...
   }
```

But it's not working .... Please help me to fixed that in code...sorry I can only give link to that code.

Comment: Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/building-multi-step-form-with-formik-yup-forked-wku1l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It was working, thanks, Please add this in answer section that I can confirm